# Find the basis for column space $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1&3\cr 5&-4&-4\cr 7&-6&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Find the basis for column space $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3\cr 5&-4&-4\cr 7&-6&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

I'm quite confused because I thought there were two methods: using the transpose or not.

By not using the transpose of $A$ and computing the RREF, I would get $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-16\cr 0&1&-19\cr 0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ for which I find that columns 1 and 2 have leading 1s. Therefore, I would go to the original matrix's columns 1 and 2 and say the basis for the column space is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 5 & 7\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -4 & -6 \end{bmatrix}.$

However, my textbook solution did the transpose method to get $$A^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&5&7\cr -1&-4&-6\cr 3&-4&2\end{bmatrix},$$ and the reduced form is $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&5&7\cr 0&1&1\cr 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The book got $\langle 1,5,7 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1 \rangle;$ however, if we reduce it further, we get $\langle 1,0,2 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1 \rangle.$

- I'm not sure whether the textbook sol of $\langle 1,5,7 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1 \rangle$ vs. $\langle 1,0,2 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1 \rangle$ is right.
- And why are all these numbers different from finding the corresponding columns from the original matrix? Is this method wrong to begin?

Comment: Fret not: your method is correct. I find that it is just a matter of preference as to which two vectors you use in your basis. Any of the three pairs of vectors you have mentioned will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these solutions give rise to the same basis. Observe that for $v_1 = (1, 5, 7)$ and $v_2 = (-1, -4, -6),$ we have that $v_3 = v_1 + v_2 = (0, 1, 1),$ from which it follows that $\operatorname{span}_k \{v_1, v_2 \} = \operatorname{span}_k \{v_1, v_3 \}.$ Of course, we could go one step further to see that $v_4 = v_1 - 5 v_3 = (1, 0, 2)$ so that $\operatorname{span}_k \{v_1, v_3 \} = \operatorname{span}_k \{v_3, v_4 \}.$